# Perimeter in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm supposed to generate two random numbers, then find the perimeter of a rectangle with them. Then it allows the User to input their answer in a EditText, when the User inputs their answer in the EditText, There is a submit button so that when the user clicks it, it lets the person know if their answer is correct or incorrect. This is displayed as a toast message. The problem i have, is when i click the submit button, it always show says "The answer is incorrect even if i put in the right value in the EditText. Would appreciate some help. Thank You

```
public class Perimeter extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perimeter);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
    public void PerimeterGame(View view) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number = rand.nextInt(12) + 1;
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand1);
        String myString = String.valueOf(number);
        myText.setText(myString);


        Random rand2 = new Random();
        int number2 = rand2.nextInt(12) + 1;
        TextView myText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand2);
        String myString2 = String.valueOf(number2);
        myText2.setText(myString2);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.question)).setText
                ("Find the perimeter of a rectange with a width of " + myString + "cm" + " and " + "length of " + myString2 + "cm" + ".");
    }
        public void AnswerCheck(View view){

          int perimeter;

            Random randOne = new Random();
            int number = randOne.nextInt(12) + 1;
            TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand1);
            String myString = String.valueOf(number);
            myText.setText(myString);


            Random randTwo = new Random();
            int number2 = randTwo.nextInt(12) + 1;
            TextView myText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand2);
            String myString2 = String.valueOf(number2);
            myText2.setText(myString2);


            EditText num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answertext);
            int val = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString() );


            perimeter=(number+number2+number+number2);

            if(val==perimeter){
                Toast.makeText(this, "The answer is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(this, "The answer is incorrect ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




    }

}
```

Comment: where did you call your methods?

Comment: have you debugged for the values properly?

Comment: I'm confused how 2 random numbers make a rectangle

Comment: From my MainActivity, i have two buttons in my main activity, one for perimeter and one for area, when i click perimeter, it starts the perimeter game

Comment: @KristiyanVarbanov `android:onClick` in the XML will call these methods.

Comment: You have to ask the user the question, Find the perimeter with the width and the length. The perimeter is the two number added multiplied by 2.

Comment: @cricket_007 seems he got other logic

Comment: why do you generate numbers in AnswerCheck?

Comment: I don't know how to leave the same numbers in the textviews when i press the submit button

Comment: i left the random numbers because i don't know how to get the values if i dont have them in AnswerCheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AnswerCheck` you dont need to generate new numbers again.. you need to get old generated numbers in first method `PerimeterGame()` and do your formula with them.

Comment: how do i get the old generated numbers?

Comment: just make it global variables and use it in two methods in first generate them and in the second do your formula

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are generating completely different random numbers when you go to check the answer. You need to save the numbers in instance variables like so.

```
public class Perimeter extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int number1, number2;
    private Random rand;

    onCreate() {
        rand = new Random();
    }

    PerimeterGame(View view) {
        number1 = rand.nextInt(12) + 1;
        number2 = rand.nextInt(12) + 1;
    }

    AnswerCheck(View view) {
        // Don't make new random variables here, just check your inputs. 
        EditText num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answertext);
        int val = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString() );


        int perimeter= 2*(number + number2);
        if (val == perimeter) { }

    }
}
```